# SQL to Spotfire query filtering issue with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, dashboard, calculated-columns, spotfire

I am trying to calculate hours flowing in and out of a cost center. When the cost center lends out an employee for an hour it's +1 and when they borrow an employee for an hour it's -1.

Right now I'm using a query that says

```
select
     columns
from dbo.table
where EmployeeCostCenter <> ProjectCostCenter
```

So when ProjectCostCenter = ID_CostCenter it returns +HoursQuantity.
Then I update ID_CostCenter = EmployeeCostCenter then where ID_CostCenter = EmployeeCostCenter to take -HoursQuantity.

That works fine. The problem is when I import it to Spotfire I can't filter on the main table even after I added the table relations. Can anyone explain why?

I can upload the actual code if needed, but I use 4 queries and a couple of them are quite lengthy. The main table, a temp table to calculate incoming hours, and a temp table to calculate outgoing hours are the only ones involved in this problem I think.

Comment: How are your relations and column matches set up? I suspect that the column matches need to be looked at, since you are probably filtering on a column that isn't the relational column.

Comment: Should I only have 1 relational column or do I pair all possible matches? I just want to be able to filter by month/year. Right now the data in the main table changes but not the data in my secondary tables. I'll post the a picture of the relation

Comment: you may only need one relational column, but the column matches must be associated as well so that Spotfire knows how to handle your filtering.

Comment: So I could have one relational column and as long as the rest are paired properly it should work? Also, thanks for always answering my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moved to answer to avoid lengthy discussion)

Essentially, data relations are used to populate filtering / marking between different data-sets. Just like in RDBMS, the relation is what Spotfire uses as the link between dataset. Essentially it's the same as the column or columns you *join* on. Thus, any column that you wish to filter in TableA and have the result set limited in TableB (or visa versa) must be a relation.

Column matches aren't related columns, but are associated for aggregations, category axis, etc within each visualization. So if TableA has "amount" and TableB has "amount debit" and you wanted to use both of these in an expression, say `Sum([TableA].[amount],[TableB].[amount debit])`, they would need to be *matched* in order to not produce erroneous results.

Lastly, once you set up your relations, you should check your filter panel to set up how you want the filtering to work. You can have the rows included, excluded, or ignored all together.  [Here is a link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.0/doc/html/filter/filter_filtering_in_related_data_tables.htm) explaining that.